# Thread Sleep and setTimeout issues

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm sure that I'm probably missing some logical element here, but on the surface it seems like what I'm doing should work.  Just to give you a the overview first, I'm using vb.net to loop through a grid view and pull values that I'm storing in session variables.  Then it opens a page through javascript and uses the session variables on the opened page to pull data from a database filling the page.  It scrapes the HTML from an overridden Render function and pulls it in to a file.

Most of that works well, but the problem is that when I use a Thread.Sleep in the loop, it sleeps for the total duration of all the pages - for instance if I open 10 pages and there's a 5 second sleep, the thread is halted for 50 seconds and then rapid fires the window.open. If I use javascript and have setTimeout pause for 5 seconds, it works the first time through but again rapid fires through the rest of the documents in the gridview.

Here's what I currently have:

```
Protected Sub ArchiveAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ArchiveAll.Click
    Dim rowcount As Integer = GridView1.Rows.Count
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim url = "foo.aspx?"
    Dim IDGrab As String = ""
    Dim IDGrab2 As String = ""




    Session("IDHolder") = Now.Year.ToString + Now.Month.ToString + Now.Day.ToString + Now.Hour.ToString + Now.Minute.ToString

    While counter < rowcount
        IDGrab = GridView1.Rows(counter).Cells(1).Text
        IDGrab2 = GridView1.Rows(counter).Cells(2).Text
        Session("FormID") = IDGrab
        Session("UserName") = IDGrab2
        WriteAction()
        counter = counter + 1

    End While


End Sub

Private Sub WriteAction()
    Dim url = "foo.aspx?"
    Response.Write("<script>setTimeout(function(){window.open('" & url & "','')},5000);</script>")
End Sub
```

So what this does - to be more precise - is five seconds after clicking ArchiveAll, it opens ~100 windows rather than opening one, waiting five seconds, and opening another.  Crash city.

So what am I missing here? I'm even ok kicking myself if it's really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of them are waiting 5 seconds, they do not queue up asynchronously. If you want to wait 5 seconds between each, you would need to increase the time between each one.

```
window.setTimeout(...,5000);
window.setTimeout(...,10000);
window.setTimeout(...,15000);
```

Better yet, build a function that takes urls out of a array.

```
var urls = ["page1.html","page2.html","page3.html"];
function openPage() {
    var url = urls.shift();
    window.open(url);
    if (urls.length) {
        window.setTimeout(openPage,5000);
    }
}
openPage();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have the timeout as a varaible that I just add 5000 to with each pass through the loop?  I'm just not sure if I could use a function like that effectively with it always opening the same page and the number of times it is opened is dynamic.

Comment: HUH!? it does not open up the same page every time. It takes it off of the array! You would build the array, better than adding 5000 script tags to the page. Plus how long are you going to sit there. 5000 * 5 seconds = 25,000 seconds = 416.17 mins = 6.94 hours. Plus if you do not close them, you are going to get memory problems. :)

Comment: No I meant I am opening the same page every time.  It opens a form page and the data is filled from a database.  It is going to be a long process but the average number of pages it will open (every two weeks) will be about a hundred.  It's basically an automation procedure for something that is much easier to do manually...